# How can I manage dynamic docker instances

Tags: docker, docker-compose

So, I need to manage and differentiate the container of a specific docker image. I use docker-container with scale to increase or decrease the images, but each of them gets modified after they are instantiated.

#### How I do nowadays:

I have a flask server. When it receives a request /< id >/start, it calls docker-compose to scale another container, then it gets the files in a folder (specified by the ID) and put inside this new container.

Finally I save in a sql database the container name associated with the id.

When I receive a request at /< id >/stop, it searches the database to get the container name and then calls docker stop "container_name".

#### The issue:

The database might desync with the container names... Due to storage restrictions, I have to purge all containers every week or so, my database might mess up at those times. Also, the container or even docker process might crash, and even if restarts, container name might change...

Is there a way do rename a container after its creation? maybe with this, I avoid needing the database and can set the container name to the ID. Would this mess up the scaling? Maybe I am overthinking and there is a better method to set this up.

Comment: This sounds like a dangerous pattern.  (What do you do if you receive a million "start" requests all at once?  Are you very very careful to avoid allowing arbitrary host directories to be mounted, arbitrary images to be executed, or arbitrary commands inside the container?)  I'd probably pick a known `docker run --name` (and not a free-form "scale up") and try very hard to avoid modifying the containers post startup.

Comment: (Setting up a job queue like RabbitMQ, some configurable/scalable number of workers on that queue, and then publishing jobs into the queue avoids the management question you're discussing here and removes the possibility of a security issue in your code rooting the host.)

Comment: Yeah... I'm aware of this request flood issue... if the ID is already instantiated in the flask app won't try to instantiate another one

Comment: I'm not being careful at all hahaha. I guess I need to rethink how to set this up... I will give a try with docker run instead of scale up... When I finish the testing I will update this question